# AWS ssl is not working in imported certificate for custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I have dobut in AWS SSL.

1. I have launched instance in AWS.
2. Then I got Public IP of launched instance, which pointed to BLUEHOST (only for domain ) DNS record ( Type A).
3. when I tried subdomain.example.com is working in browser.
4. Then for SSL, I imported certificate key and crt in certificate manager.And 
   certificate status is ISSUED.
5. When I tried HTTPS in browser ( https://subdomain.example.com ) is not working

Any one guide me.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the certificate provided by Amazon Certificate Manager(ACM) on EC2 instance. That can only be used with certain AWS services such as Elastic Load Balancer, CloudFront, API Gateway and Elastic Beanstalk.

If you want to use ACM, you can setup a ELB in front of your EC2 instance and have your certificate applied to ELB. When you are requesting for a certificate via ACM make sure to add `*.example.com` domain to protect your subdomain as well.

[image]

If you want to setup SSL on your EC2 instance itself, you can request for SSL certificates from a ssl certificate provider. There are many certificate providers, such as [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), [sslforfree](https://www.sslforfree.com) etc..

Here is a [guide](https://www.geekybits.in/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-amazon-ec2-linux-ami/) on how to install SSL certificates obtained from a certificate provider on your EC2 instance.

Comment: Yes. There are many providers. I have updated the answer. Thanks @Uwe